# yelp error :MISSING_PARAMETER

Tags: oauth, yelp

I am new to yelp API. I am using version2. I did sign up for API access and got, Consumer Key,Consumer secret, token, token_secret, then I used to the following link
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?[http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=San%2BFrancisco&oauth_consumer_key=SOMEKEY&oauth_consumer_secret=SOMESECRET&oauth_token=SOMETOKEN&oauth_token_secret=SOMESECRET](http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=San%2bFrancisco&oauth_consumer_key=%22eJfdn0UvEYUQwyGuyECvtA%22&oauth_consumer_secret=%229kGchc4UpviQk6vuvS1RJ9FHHqI%22&oauth_token=Rf45r04jUM_R11e1EwyoHtUbqEUBK4yU%22&oauth_token_secret=%22hxpTMf-b63A6UpuxP2cM1dP2lvc%22)

to get the data but then I get a series of **MISSING_PARAMETER** errors. For signature_method I used HMAC-SHA1 but for the rest (oauth_signature, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp) I iddn't know what to put, so i used an empty field but then I got **"INVALID CREDENTIAL"** error. How do I get these missing fields?
They are not in my API access page.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/olalonde/node-yelp but I still get missing_parameter response

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't publish your keys like that, you need to run a script to "encrypt" them and once you "send" those keys you handshake with yelp and than make a query for the search you are trying to get results for.

Basically you need a script in your preferred language (PHP for example) to make the query. a good start might be https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2